# Divide monthly summary of column by value in other column using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I have a dataframe called `df` that looks like this:

```
id    date      year  month day value      QC start_yr end_yr series_length                                         
                                    
275 28/09/2010  2010    9   28  1.36159873  1   2010    2020    11
275 29/09/2010  2010    9   29  1.43747532  1   2010    2020    11
275 30/09/2010  2010    9   30  1.15989387  1   2010    2020    11
275 01/10/2010  2010    10  1   1.34619892  1   2010    2020    11
275 02/10/2010  2010    10  2   1.55105293  1   2010    2020    11
275 03/10/2010  2010    10  3   1.37231886  1   2010    2020    11
275 04/10/2010  2010    10  4   1.02093196  1   2010    2020    11
275 05/10/2010  2010    10  5   1.70137763  1   2010    2020    11
275 06/10/2010  2010    10  6   1.64840853  1   2010    2020    11
275 07/10/2010  2010    10  7   1.92625344  1   2010    2020    11
275 08/10/2010  2010    10  8   1.07618248  1   2010    2020    11
275 09/10/2010  2010    10  9   1.04859626  1   2010    2020    11
275 10/10/2010  2010    10  10  0.77795529  1   2010    2020    11
275 11/10/2010  2010    10  11  1.42359686  1   2010    2020    11
275 12/10/2010  2010    10  12  0.91871309  1   2010    2020    11
275 13/10/2010  2010    10  13  0.89544863  1   2010    2020    11
275 14/10/2010  2010    10  14  0.56718421  1   2010    2020    11
275 15/10/2010  2010    10  15  0.70719278  1   2010    2020    11
```

(with thousands of other rows)

I want to create a summary dataset which groups by id and sums the value on a monthly basis, and divides by the series_length, to give an overall monthly average

I can do this for each individual station by using:

```
mean_monthly <- df %>%
  group_by(id, month) %>%
  summarise(monthly_value = sum(value)/11)
```

and this works fine for the first id which has a series length of 11, but other ids have a series_length of between 1 and 30. So dividing these by 11 gives incorrect information. I want to summarise so that I create a new dataset which sums all the `value` values on a monthly basis, and divides by the series_length automatically, without me having to specify the number like I have done with '11' above.

I hope this makes sense and would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: `summarise(monthly_value = sum(value)/series_length)` doesn't work?

Comment: Use `n()` to find number in `group_by`: `summarise(monthly_value = sum(value)/n())`

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko it returns a df with the same amount of rows as the daily one, with multiple entries for `month` all with the same `value`. I think the solution from the other comment works however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `series_length` is *repeated* you could also use `min`, `max`, `mean`, or `last` instead of `first`. They would all return the same value.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id, month) %>% 
  summarize(monthly_value = sum(value) / first(series_length))
```

If `series_length` is just a count of the number of observations in your `group_by` then you can also use `n()`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id, month) %>% 
  summarize(monthly_value = sum(value) / n())
```

I'm not sure if this is the case because in your repex when `month` is 10 there are more than 11 observations (the value in `series_length`).

Comment: `series_length` is the difference between `start_year ` and `end_year ` so is repeated for each `id` but is also different for each `id`. I think your first solution works - does it associate the `first` with the `id`? If so it should work. i.e. does it take a value of 11 for id number 275, but a value of 30 which is the `series_length `for `id` number 550?

Comment: `first` will get the first value of `series_length` from each unique combination of `id` and `month`.